# How to serialize ManyToManyField

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I want to serialize ManyToManyField but at the same time, I am looking for something which updates the same using ModelViewSet. I am able to serialize it but when I am updating it I am not able to. I know I can make a separate API for that but due to some requirements, I need to stick to one endpoint. Here is my code

```
class ComponentSerializers(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = coreModel.Component
        fields = '__all__'

class MonitorSerializers(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    device = ComponentSerializers(read_only=True, many=True) 
    class Meta:
        model = models.Monitor
        fields = '__all__'
        read_only_fields = ('id', 'created_at', 'updated_at',)
```

and views.py is

```
class MonitorViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    authentication_classes = (authentication.TokenAuthentication,)
    permission_classes = (permissions.IsAuthenticated,)
    queryset = models.Monitor.objects.all()
    filter_backends = (DjangoFilterBackend,OrderingFilter,SearchFilter)
    filter_class = superFilter.MonitorFilters
    serializer_class = serializers.MonitorSerializers
```

Comment: What do you mean by "updating it I am not able to"?

Comment: I want to update `device ` PATCH request

Comment: read_only=True flag is there for device attribute

Comment: When I remove that then i get an error as Dict is required

Comment: `{
    "device": [
        {
            "non_field_errors": [
                "Invalid data. Expected a dictionary, but got int."
            ]
        },
        {
            "non_field_errors": [
                "Invalid data. Expected a dictionary, but got int."
            ]
        }
    ]
}`

Answer (score 0):

If you want update [ManytoMany or Related objects](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#dealing-with-nested-objects)

Override

```
def update(self, validated_data):
```

in MonitorSerializers

```
class MonitorSerializers(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    device = ComponentSerializers(read_only=True, many=True)
    device_ids = serializers.ListField(write_only=True,
         child = serializers.IntegerField(min_value = 1))
     ....


def update(self, instance, validated_data):
    # Remove component data and save in variable
    iscomponentdataexists = 'device_ids' in validated_data
    if iscomponentdataexists :
        componentdata= validated_data.pop('device_ids')
    instance = super().update(instance, validated_data)  # Update Monitor Data
    # looping through new device_ids list
    if iscomponentdataexists :
        for deviceid in componentdata:
            try:
                obj = coreModel.Component.objects.get(id=deviceid)
                instance.devices.add(obj)
            except coreModel.Component.DoesNotExist:
                pass
        instance.save()
        
    return instance
```

Remove **read_only=True** from device

Comment: I am still getting the same error.

Comment: yes I have done..

Comment: You got which error?
post your json payload used for patch request

Comment: `{   
    "device": [1,2]
}`

Comment: then you need to change your serializer with existing serializer you need to provide data of components not ids {"device":[{...},{....}]}

Comment: Edited Answer accordingly

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/240090/discussion-between-sai-vineeth-and-piyush).